# .htaccess rewrite two variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my current rewrite line

```
RewriteRule ^cam/([^/]+) /index.php?cate=$1[L]
```

however after the `cate=$1` I need to define another variable I need to define the `$currentpage`

so `RewriteRule ^cam/([^/]+)/`?`/index.php?cate=$1&currentpage=`?`[L]`

I have put two unstyled question marks where I'm not sure what would go there. Thankyou for any help and I hope I've made it clear what I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteRule ^cam/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?cate=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cam/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?cate=$1 [NC,L]
```